# Fatal Error when transforming a XSL with Java 1.8.0_251

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, xalan

When trying to transform the stylesheet I get the following error from Java 1.8.0_251. Yet the same stylesheet transform without any issues with Java 1.8.0_241. I get the error when the line tFactory.newTransformer(stylesheet); is executed.

Also using xalan 2.7.2 instead of the Java 1.8.0._251 works as well but that version os xalan is really old.

Has anyone come across something like this? If so how to solve it?

SimpleNotWorking04.xsl
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pUiMvVtVBmBvCwfPXNW__pXVCiS4c3RV/view?usp=sharing

SimpleWorking04.xsl
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OsOflQzGErvVFVsrmriqa0gbODS2OWi5/view?usp=sharing

If you diff the two above files it's just one blank line added to the SimpleNotWorking04.xsl that gives this error.

NOTE the number after "Not targeting" (e.g. Not targeting 10980:) will change depending on the XSL content.

> ```
> com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ClassGenException: Not   
> targeting 10980: nop[0](1), but null ERROR:Not targeting 10980:   
> nop[0](1), but null
>
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.BranchInstruction.updateTarget(BranchInstruction.java:217)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.outline(MethodGenerator.java:1738)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.outlineChunks(MethodGenerator.java:1169)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.getGeneratedMethods(MethodGenerator.java:1899)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.ClassGenerator.addMethod(ClassGenerator.java:137)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileNamedTemplate(Mode.java:557)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileTemplates(Mode.java:566)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileApplyTemplates(Mode.java:825)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.compileModes(Stylesheet.java:622)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.translate(Stylesheet.java:735)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:478)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:553)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:947)
>  at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:761)
>  at simpletest.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:24) ERROR:  'Could not      compile stylesheet' FATAL ERROR:  'Not targeting 10980:
> nop[0](1), but     null'
>            :Not targeting 10980: nop[0](1), but null
> ```

The code is simple and is as below.

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import java.io.File;

public class SimpleTest {

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         StreamSource stylesheet = new StreamSource(new File("SimpleNotWorking04.xsl"));
         TransformerFactory tFactory =TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
         Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesheet);
      }
      catch(TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
          System.out.println("ERROR:"+tce.getMessage());
      }
      catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("ERROR:"+e.getMessage());
      }
      catch(Throwable t){
         System.out.println("ERROR:"+t.getMessage());
      }
      System.out.println("Done transformation!!");
   }

}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us the contents of SimpleNotWorking04.xsl, please.

Comment: Add two XSLs one that is working and the other that is not.

SimpleNotWorking04.xsl https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pUiMvVtVBmBvCwfPXNW__pXVCiS4c3RV/view?usp=sharing

SimpleWorking04.xsl https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OsOflQzGErvVFVsrmriqa0gbODS2OWi5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Remove `.getMessage()` from your println statements.  A message without its corresponding exception type is rarely helpful.  (For example: `System.out.println("ERROR: " + tce);`  Even better would be `tce.printStackTrace();`.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Java 8 251 version. After reporting it to Oracle it was fix and released with Java 8 271 October 2020 release.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue. I fixed it by breaking the big if condition in to multiple if conditions.