# Large XSLT (~10000 lines) failed to transform input message (Xalan)

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0, xalan

I am facing a classic problem, I have an XSLT with ~10000 lines and trying to use Java for transformation

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("convertor.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
```

But unfortunately ended up with below error:

```
com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ClassGenException: Not targeting 45269: nop[0](1), but null
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.BranchInstruction.updateTarget(BranchInstruction.java:217)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.outline(MethodGenerator.java:1721)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.outlineChunks(MethodGenerator.java:1168)
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2704015_1.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62449124/14419